# How to make a semi - shading stripe in resume with LaTeX

Tags: color, framed, highlighting

I want to make some semi-shading strips in resume to highlight each field, like this image:

[image]

However, the template code which I use is as below:

```
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
%
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
 \vspace{8pt}
 \parbox{\textwidth}{%
  \setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
   \begin{shaded}
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
   \framebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}
    \fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{%
     \textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1}\vphantom{p\^{E}}}}%
    }%
   }%
  \end{shaded}
 }%
 \vspace{-10pt}%
}
%
\resheading{Education}
```

and the result looks like this:

[image]

Could you tell me how to change this template code in order to get the first picture above? I tried several times, but all failed.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
The full title and package used in this template is as below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,13pt]{article}

\newlength{\outerbordwidth}

\pagestyle{empty}

\raggedbottom

\raggedright

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{1pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)

\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars

%-----------------------------------------------------------

%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}

\setlength{\headheight}{-0.25in}

\setlength{\headsep}{0in}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}

\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

\setlength{\textheight}{10in}

\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}

\setlength{\topskip}{0in}

\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}

\setlength{\parskip}{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
```

Comment: what packages are used?  It helps to give a complete MWE, starting with `\documentclass`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I already added the package above, do you have some clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes were needed:

1) in the preamble `\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{0pt}` instead of 1pt

2) in the `\resheading` macro, add `\fboxrule=0pt` to remove the box border.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,13pt]{article}

\newlength{\outerbordwidth}

\pagestyle{empty}

\raggedbottom

\raggedright

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{0pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)

\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars

%-----------------------------------------------------------

%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}

\setlength{\headheight}{-0.25in}

\setlength{\headsep}{0in}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}

\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

\setlength{\textheight}{10in}

\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}

\setlength{\topskip}{0in}

\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}

\setlength{\parskip}{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}

\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}

  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}

    \begin{shaded}
\fboxrule=0pt
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}

    \end{shaded}

  }\vspace{-10pt}

}

\resheading{Education}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The bar color can be darkened by lowering the value of `shadecolorB` in the preamble.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\rule[-5pt]{1pt}{20pt}%
\hspace{10pt}%
\colorbox[gray]{.9}{%
\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-11pt\relax][l]{Education}}

\bigskip

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: very appreciate your answer, but I still want to modify based this template code

Comment: I wonder how this kind of titling can be implemented inside a two-sided document in order to work correctly with `fancyhdr`... Maybe I'll follow up this as a separated question.